# How to remove exact word from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a string

```
TestString = "{Item:ABC, Item:DEF, Item:GHI}";
```

How can I remove all of the "Item:"s.
I have tried to use

```
msg = TestString.replace(/[\Item:/&]+/g, "");
```

but this unfortunately removes all the Is, Ts. Es and M,s from any letters that may follow.

How can I remove the exact text
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to remove text from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/javascript-how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Comment: Assuming its valid JavaScript, you could use `JSON.parse` and `Object.values`. Note that your example is not valid JSON, but if its from a trusted source you could use `eval` in place of `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I did look at that thread. And when I used it I found it to be removing the the letters any time they came up and were not part of Item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be simple, you can directly create a Regex like `/Item:/g`,

```js
var TestString = "{Item:ABC, Item:DEF, Item:GHI}";
var msg = TestString.replace(/Item:/g, "");
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
/Item:/g
```

for replacing `Item:`.

The fomer regular expression

```
/[\Item:/&]+/g
```

used a character class with single letters instead of a string.

```js
var TestString = "{Item:ABC, Item:DEF, Item:GHI}",
    msg = TestString.replace(/Item:/g, "");

console.log(msg);
```