# Delete identical elements from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Got string, need to delete same words from there.

Here is my code. I tried to split string into array and then sort but it didn't work. It didn't even go through my `if`. I would like to hear your advice and maybe working code :)

```
  var str = "I wont go anywhere as soon as I wont go there";
    var array = str.split(" ");
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = str;
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML = array;
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].innerHTML = array;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/javascript-how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't check every array element with every other array element.

Your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
                array.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
```

Just checks array elements in sequence.

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
          if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
                array.splice(i, 1);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked! By the way i tried double loop i and j as you wrote but unfortunately i forgot to add && i != j to if :)

Comment: @ttmcswg Glad to help you out. If it worked please accept my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you like one-lines try this

```
var reducedString  = array.reduce(function(out, s) {
    return out.indexOf(s) == -1 ? out + ' ' + s : out;
},'').substring(1);
```

or in ES6

```
var reducedString = array.reduce( (out, s) => out.indexOf(s) == -1 ? out + ' ' + s : out);
```

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but +1 for ES6!

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr thanks :), I recently discovered array.reduce(), saves a lot of space

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ES6 Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with the spread syntax after splitting the sentance:

```js
const str = "I wont go anywhere as soon as I wont go there";
const unique = [...new Set(str.split(' '))].join(' ');

console.log(unique);
```

In ES5 you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a dictionary object.

```js
var str = "I wont go anywhere as soon as I wont go there";

var dict = Object.create(null); // creates an empty object, without inherited properties and methods
var unique = str.split(' ').reduce(function(arr, w) {
  if(!dict[w]) {
    arr.push(w);
    dict[w] = true;
  }
  
  return arr;
}, []).join(' ');

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the substring you are searching for

```
var ret = "data-123".replace('data-','');
console.log(ret);
```