# How to remove text from JSON entry being appended onto webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a webpage that takes a JSON via `var url = myReport.json` and displays information. The information it displays are server information that I am monitoring.

The server information monitors all applications running on the server, but it filters back ones that are named `company_name_` and looks like this:

```
company_name_app1
company_name_app2
company_name_app3
company_name_app4
company_name_app5
```

On the html page, I want to remove the strings `company_name_` so that the webpage will just display the following:

```
app1
app2
app3
app4
app5
```

Is there a way to remove a specified string match from the JSON entries so I can display it as wanted above?

EDIT:

```
<script>
    //define a function that will fetch status and set icon URL
    function setServerProcessesServer1761() {
        var url = "Server1761.json";
        var $svc = $("#Server1761-processes"); //get a reference to your <div>

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            document.getElementById("Server1761-processes").innerHTML = data.processes.filter(s => s.Name.value.includes("company_name")).map(s => `<tr><td>${s.Name.value}</td> <td>${s.Status}</td></tr>`).join('\n');
            $('#Server1761-processes').html(function (_, html) { return html.replace(/runn1ng/g,"<img src='smallgreen.png' />")});
            $('#Server1761-processes').html(function (_, html) { return html.replace(/fai1ed/g,"<img src='smallred.png' />")});
        }); // you will have to concatenate the entire services request line on line 130
    }

    //special jQuery syntax to run when document is ready (like onload but better)
    $(function() {
        setServerProcessesServer1761();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/javascript-how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.Name.value.replace("company_name_", "");
```

The above will replace `company_name_`part in the string with nothing. It uses the `replace` method from the `String` object.

> String.replace(input (String, Regex), replace (String, Function))

Comment: Hi Mouser, thank you for the feedback. Where would I insert this? Do I need to wrap it in a function? Or declare a variable? I updated my post with my `<script>`.

Comment: Hi Mouser, sorry I am having difficulty understanding this solution. I notice you edited your post, but where exactly does it need to be inserted in order to work? Again I am new to JavaScript I am sorry I am having difficulty understanding your solution. Thank you again!

Comment: In the first line after `$_getJSON` there is a `s.Name.value` just after the `=>`

Comment: Thank you again Mouser. So I got it to work and inserted it in the `s.Name.value` of line like you recommended, but I noticed it only applies to the first entry. If I want it to apply to the rest of my entries, I have to continue to write `.replace("company_name_", "")` for all entries. Since I have 5, I ended up writing `.replace("company_name_", "").replace("company_name_", "").replace("company_name_", "").replace("company_name_", "").replace("company_name_", "");`. Is there a way to add a loop into this without rewriting?

Comment: I found the solution: `.replace(/company_name_/g, "");`