# Strip HTML pound sign from string to create number

Tags: javascript, string, sum, numbers, strip

I am trying to create a script that adds two strings that are pulled from a database. The script pulls the data correctly, but the strings contain a pound sign (£) - so consequently the numbers won't add together as they're effectively text strings.

```
var subtotal = "&pound;25";
var shipping = "&pound;5";

var total = subtotal + shipping;
```

How can I strip the pound signs from the code so that the numbers will add up?

Comment: so [replace it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and convert it to a number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove text from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove all characters except digits and dots from the string using the string replace method with a regular expression, then call parseFloat on the result to cast it to a number.

```js
const toNumber = n => parseFloat(n.replace(/[^.0-9]/g, ''));
var subtotal = "&pound;25";
var shipping = "&pound;5";

var total = toNumber(subtotal) + toNumber(shipping);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach may be

```
var total = parseFloat(subtotal.replace(/[^.0-9]g/,'')) + parseInt(shipping..replace(/[^.0-9]g/,''));
```

```js
var subtotal = "&pound;19.99";
var shipping = "&pound;3.95";
var total = parseFloat(subtotal.replace(/[^.0-9]/g,'')) + parseFloat(shipping.replace(/[^.0-9]/g,''));

console.log(total);
console.log(total.toFixed(2)); // to round to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Please search for duplicates before answering questions.

Comment: Thanks. I've given this a go, and it works, except it doesn't add up the numbers after the decimal places:
````
var subTotal = '&pound;19.99';
var Shipping = '&pound;3.95';
var total = parseInt(subTotal.replace('&pound;','')) + parseInt(Shipping.replace('&pound;',''));

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"The total of your order is: " + total;
````

Comment: just use parseFloat instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help. I've achieved this now as below:

```
const toNumber = n => parseFloat(n.replace(/[^.0-9]/g, ''));
var subtotal = "&pound;25.53";
var shipping = "&pound;5.30";

var total = toNumber(subtotal) + toNumber(shipping);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"The total of your order is: " + total.toFixed(2);
```

Returns the correct total of 30.83!