# Parse Json in Javascript - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, json, google-tag-manager

I do have that script:

```
function() {
  var publishedDate = "";
  var yoastInfo = JSON.parse(document.head.querySelector('.yoast-schema-graph.yoast-schema-graph--main').innerHTML);
  vars = yoastInfo["@graph"];
  for(var i in vars) {
    if(vars[i]['@type'] === 'WebPage') {
      pubDateRaw=(vars[i]['datePublished']);
      break;
    }
  }
  publishedDate.concat(pubDateRaw.substring(0,4),pubDateRaw.substring(5,7),pubDateRaw.substring(8,10));
  return publishedDate;
}
```

When I run the code, it gives me a `""` instead of the date.

here is the json:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph": [   

    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "id234234",
      "url": "https://www.whatevver.com",
      "inLanguage": "de-DE",
      "name": "this is the name",
      "isPartOf": {
        "@id": "id234234
      },
      "primaryImageOfPage": {
        "@id": "id234234"
      },
      "datePublished": "2020-01-14T07:46:12+00:00",
      "dateModified": "2020-01-15T08:04:50+00:00",
      "description": "description "
    },

  ]
}
```

So i need to extract the datePubished from that json. What is wrong with my code?

**Edit**

With the help of you guys, I made this script:

```
function() {
  var publishedDate = "";
  var yoastInfo = JSON.parse(document.head.querySelector('.yoast-schema-graph.yoast-schema-graph--main').innerHTML); 
  vars = yoastInfo["@graph"];
  for(var i in vars) {
    if(vars[i]['@type'] === 'WebPage') {
      publishedDate=(vars[i]['datePublished']); 
    }
  }



  return publishedDate;
}
```

now I need to cut the dateTime `2020-01-14T07:46:12+00:00` to `2020-01-14`
what would be the best solution?

**EDIT2**

Found the Solution at:  [To the Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Comment: Basically, You just want to return datePublised from the given JSON?

Comment: didn't you try some debug stuff in your for loop ? seems the condition is never met

Comment: Yes basically i want to return the datePubished - and push it into a datalayer.

Comment: Ok I got it. How exactly do you want the date format?

Comment: If Updated my question, the result should be YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given JSON :

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph": [   

    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "id234234",
      "url": "https://www.whatevver.com",
      "inLanguage": "de-DE",
      "name": "this is the name",
      "isPartOf": {
        "@id": "id234234" // MAKE IT AS A STRING
      },
      "primaryImageOfPage": {
        "@id": "id234234"
      },
      "datePublished": "2020-01-14T07:46:12+00:00",
      "dateModified": "2020-01-15T08:04:50+00:00",
      "description": "description "
    },

  ]
}
```

```
function() {
  let publishedDate = "";
  const yoastInfo = JSON.parse(document.head.querySelector('.yoast-schema- 
  graph.yoast-schema-graph--main').innerHTML); // I HOPE YOURE ABLE TO EXTRACT THE JSON HERE IN yoastInfo.
  vars = yoastInfo["@graph"];
  for(var i in vars) {
    if(vars[i]['@type'] === 'WebPage') {
      publishedDate=(vars[i]['datePublished']); // YOU ARE GETTING EMPTY STRING BECAUSE YOU'RE SETTING VARIABLE CALLED 'publishedDate' AND SETTING VALUE IN 'pubDateRaw'.
    }
  }
  return publishedDate;
}
```

PLEASE FOLLOW THE COMMENTS IN THE CODE FOR CLARIFICATION. THANKS :))

And check the link for more clarification: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gahzsrvj/1/

Comment: Yeah, with a little modification for Tagmanager (ES6) it worked. maybe you can help me again? Now I get the whole Time Date String, but i only need YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('/');
}

formatDate(publishedDate);

You can use moment.js for more simplification.