# Remove last 3 letters of html div content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to remove last 3 characters of div text content. Div ID is `time`

Trying with this code so far

```
function Slice() {
var TimeString = document.getElementById("time").textContent = Result;
var Result = TimeString.slice (0, -3);
}
```

With not success result

Hope can help me

Comment: Put `document.getElementById("time")` into a variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/how-to-remove-text-from-a-string

Comment: You're using the `Result` variable to assign `textContent` before `Result` is assigned itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```js
function slice() {
  var t = document.getElementById("time");
  t.textContent = t.textContent.slice(0, -3);
}
slice();
```

```html
<p id="time">1234567890</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this that:

```js
function Slice() {
const TimeString = document.getElementById("time").textContent;
const Result = TimeString.slice (0, -3);
document.getElementById("time").textContent = Result;
}

Slice()
```

```html
<div id="time">12344</div>
```

or better

```js
function Slice(id) {
const el = document.getElementById(id)
const TimeString = el.textContent;
const Result = TimeString.slice (0, -3);
el.textContent = Result;
}

Slice("time")
```

```html
<div id="time">12344</div>
```