# how to remove Characters from a string in react.js

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving data in this form

```
('FCA',)
('JP NIC',)
('JP CHI',)
('2022-03-04T07:18:36.468Z',)
```

I want to clean up to remove Brackets, string quote and comma

```
FCA
JP NIC
JP CHI
2022-03-04T07:18:36.468Z
```

I'm trying to use `substring()` But problem is number of characters in this data can be changed but these value are constant and I want to remove them `('',)`. How I can do this ?

Comment: It would be better to clear up the issues you have with why your server is sending you terrible data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex and `string.replace`

```
string.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
```

just put whatever string you want to ignore inside the rectangular brackets, i.e - `string.replace(/[YOUR_IGNORED_CHARACTERS]/g, "")`

you can read more about regex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```js
const regex = /\('([^']+)',\)/g

const output = input.replace(regex, '$1');

//   explain:  /  \(  '  (   [^']+  )  ',\)  /  g

//             1   2  3  4    5     6   7    8  9
```

- 1: start regex
- 2: match character `(`  (character `/` to escape)
- 3: match character `'`
- 4: start group in regex
- 5: match character not `'`
- 6: close group in regex
- 7: match `',)`
- 8: end regex
- 9: make this regex match global (don't need if you want replace one time)
- `$1` in code is first group match regex (start with 4 and end with 6)

```js
const input = `('FCA',)
('JP NIC',)
('JP CHI',)
('2022-03-04T07:18:36.468Z',)`;

const output = input.replace(/\('([^']+)',\)/g, '$1');

console.log(input)
console.log('// =>')
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex replacement with a capture group:

```js
var inputs = ["('FCA',)", "('JP NIC',)", "('JP CHI',)", "('2022-03-04T07:18:36.468Z',)"];
var outputs = inputs.map(x => x.replace(/\('(.*?)',\)/g, "$1"));
console.log(outputs);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for String.Replace.

Replace: You can specify characters or even strings to be replaced in string.

[How to remove text from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Maybe i would create a custom method that handles the replacing and call that method with the proper parameters.