# Given a string containing URLS and words filter out the urls and keep only the words

Tags: javascript

Given a regex how can i split filter a string like this :

```
"https://theuselessweb.com/ hello https://theuselessweb.com/ hello"
```

To a string like this :

```
"hello hello"
```

Ive tried something like

```
string.match(regex).join(' ')
```

But this doesnt reeally work
Any solutions?

Comment: What exactly is the desired outcome? Is your input string a list of words delimited by `' '` and you want to extract words that are not an `url`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398955 Replace substrings matching a URL with the empty string

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way by splitting the string into words and then filtering out the urls.

```js
const str = "https://theuselessweb.com/ hello https://theuselessweb.com/ hello";

const res = str.split(" ").filter(w => !w.includes("https://")).join(" ");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input by `split(' ')` and filter out the array using a regex expression you want.

```js
const inputStr = "https://theuselessweb.com/ hello https://theuselessweb.com/ hello";

const inputArr = inputStr.split(' ');
const regex = new RegExp('https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}');

const output = inputArr.filter(word => !regex.test(word));
console.log(output);
```